# Is it good practice to use Build.VERSION_CODES? If so, why?

Tags: android

Is there any particular reason to use [Build.VERSION_CODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES). E.g.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

}
```

to check for API levels as opposed to just check a numeric constant. E.g.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {

}
```

IMHO, using numeric constants keeps things simple when reading code, since you don't have to remember which number is which version.

Was wondering if there's any value to using `Build.VERSION_CODES` that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a matter of which makes the code more readable to you. For instance, if you asked me which API level forces you to call `startForegroundService()`, I could tell you it's "Oreo" but I couldn't tell you which numeric API constant is assigned to Oreo.

Answer (score 0):

See the API doc [Build.VERSION_CODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES) and [SDK_INT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)

> Enumeration of the currently known SDK version codes. These are the values that can be found in [VERSION#SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK). Version numbers increment monotonically with each official platform release.

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is nothing but a constant integer which corresponds to each Android release version, e.g. Android L, M, O, etc. It is true that using numeric constants keeps things simple when reading code, but you also loose the convenience to navigate code to the proper Android API documentation if not suing [Build.VERSION_CODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES). It is more like a convention of how do you communicate different Android releases among your team members.